# Send out API Response in Chunks to React Native Application

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, api, react-native

So, this is basically to improve the user experience. My App makes a request to backend API, which in turn makes a series of API requests simultaneously, and it takes about 30 seconds for fetching all the information. So, optimizing the speed is not in my hands. It depends on external APIs response time.

So, the only thing I can do from my end is, as soon as certain datas are ready, I want to send it to the application for the users, so that, users may not feel like waiting for such a long time.

I read about web sockets and thought this could be my solution. I just want to be sure though.

Is this achievable through **Web Sockets** ? If not, any other better solution?

Also any links which could help me in solving this will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you want the data to be streamed back to the client in chunks, then yes, I would say Web sockets would be the way to go.

Comment: You can also try this solution: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/ it's especially useful for big files you can even stop streaming while you download part of data you want. Similar solution: https://jakearchibald.com/2016/streams-ftw/

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Can you point me to any link that might be useful, that actually explains on how to integrate it along with redux, redux-saga and all ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have any links for that saved. Start by reading up on "using websockets with php" and go through a couple of guides and play around with it. When you got the hang of it, you can try and connect it with your current front end.